# Magento, how to set up language from code

Tags: magento

I was wondering, if there is any way to set mangeto language for specific area from Code?
What i mean is lets say i want a custom page to be in Spanish while other pages in my website in English.

Comment: Add custom drop down with language option and onChange event of dorpdown jus set a custom cookie for this.

Answer (score 0):

Set cookie onChange event of custom drop in following manner

```
$cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
```

$cookie->set('selectedlang', 'spanish' ,time()+86400,'/');

and then make a if else statement

```
if($cookie->get('selectedlang')=='spanish')
```

//Show your spanish content

else

//Show your default content

Comment: is this usefull for your requirment?